# How do I filter based on multiple properties in angular 7

Tags: angular, filter, properties, pipe

I am new to working with Angular and now am learning how to create a pipe to filter data. I was able to do so but can somebody give me ideas on how to filter based on multiple properties

filtering by name

```
 <mat-card  *ngFor="let item of model | searchFilter:searchTerm">
<mat-card-title>
  {{ item.title }}
</mat-card-title>
```

now I have to filter based on item properties

```
<mat-card-content>
  <div *ngFor="let property of item.properties">
    {{ (property.labelVisible ? property.label + ' ' : '') + property.value }}
  </div>
```

search filter pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Card} from "./card";

@Pipe({
name:'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
transform(model: Card<any>[], searchTerm:string):Card<any>[]
{
if(!model || !searchTerm){
  return model
}
return model.filter(item =>item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase())!== -1)
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  For searchTerm in component file don't make it as string, make it as a object which has all your object properties like below


   searchTerm = {title: "", location: "" ...}

   and in the search filter pipe**        


import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Card } from "./card";

@Pipe({
     name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(model: Card<any>[], searchTerm: Object): Card<any>[] {
          if (!model || !searchTerm) {
               return model
          }
          return model.filter(item => {
               return Object.keys(item).filter(function (key, index) {
                    return 
          item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm[key].toLowerCase()) 
          !== -1
               }).length > 0;

          })
     }
}

 *OR*

 use module ngx-filter-pipe, which makes life easier
 do npm  i -S ngx-filter-pipe
 then import the module appModule then in the component add following code

             sampleData = [{id:1, name:'xyz', location:'india'},
                       {id:2, name:'abc', location: 'USA'}
                     ]
              userFilter: any = { name: '' , location: ''};

        And HTML part looks like this


        //add search box here for multiple inputs
        <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let user of users | filterBy: userFilter">{{ user.name }}</li>

              <!-- in case you want to show empty message -->
              <li *ngIf="(users | filterBy: userFilter).length === 0">No matching elements</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: I think a dynamic function that loops through the searchTerm will be a better approach. But this solution will definitely solve the problem. tnx!

Comment: @valhallarossferrer tnx for your suggestion, Now i have edited the answer to handle n number of columns without changing the code..

Comment: i am using the ngx-filter-pipe. I have another doubt. What if the properties are inside an array just like in the picture i attached above. I do I give that in the userFilter @ajaykumarmp

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advice not to use pipe for filtering data, there is a performance penalty to pay and also it can prevent aggressive minification of your project, Appendix section explains it https://angular.io/guide/pipes.

The better option is just call component function which does the required filtering or if you need yo use the same filtering in many places, you can use injected angular services https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services